# Generate next combination in lexicographic order

Tags: c++, combinatorics

C++'s standard library has a `std::next_permutation` algorithm but no `next_combination`. The reason behind this absence is, I guess, that one of the easiest and fastest way to generate combinations one at a time is to rely on the permutations of a vector of boolean values, which is then used as a sieve to retain the elements in the combination. The drawback is that you need to maintain some state to compute the next permutation.

Here's a try at a STL style next_combination state-less algorithm. The range `[begin, end)` contains the whole set of elements, and `[begin, begin+k)` the current combination of k elements. The next combination is generated in place.

I'd be grateful for advice and improvement suggestions.

NB1: the algorithm depends on two invariants: `[begin, begin+k]` is sorted, and `[begin+k, end)` is sorted also.

NB2: I've tried to rely on existing STL algorithms as much as possible.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

template <typename Iterator>
Iterator find_next_increase_position(Iterator begin, Iterator combination_end, Iterator end);

template <typename Iterator>
bool next_combination(Iterator begin, Iterator end, unsigned k) {
    const auto combination_end = begin+k;
    const auto next_move = find_next_increase_position(begin, combination_end, end);
    if (next_move == end) return false;
    const auto previous_value = *next_move;
    std::inplace_merge(next_move, combination_end, end);
    const auto next_rotation =
        std::rotate(next_move, std::upper_bound(next_move, end, previous_value), end);
    std::rotate(combination_end, next_rotation, end);
    return true;
}

template <typename Iterator>
Iterator find_next_increase_position(Iterator begin, Iterator combination_end, Iterator end) {
    auto pos = std::upper_bound(std::reverse_iterator(combination_end),
                                    std::reverse_iterator(begin),
                                    *--end,
                                    std::greater<typename Iterator::value_type>());
    if (pos.base() == begin)
        return ++end;
    return --pos.base();
}
```

An example:

```
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> test{1,2,3,4,5};
    while (next_combination(test.begin(), test.end(), 3)) {
        for (auto i : test) std::cout << i;    
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

With output:

```
12435
12534
13425
13524
14523
23415
23514
24513
34512
```

Edit: added `#include`s and example

Comment: Are you missing some `#include` lines?  It looks like you need (at least) `#include <algorithm>` and `#include <iterator>`.

Answer (score 1):

My advice here is this: throw away your requirement of not having any state. The number sequence \$\binom{i}{\lceil i \rceil}\$ grows fast, so you won't be able to deal with combinations whose state is "large". Also, I see no point doing templates here. Instead you could write a simple class that manages indices in such a way that indirection is lexicographic:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

class lexicographical_combination_generator {
public:
    lexicographical_combination_generator(size_t set_size,
                                          size_t combination_size);
    bool increment();
    size_t get_set_size()                      { return m_set_size; }
    size_t get_combination_size()              { return m_combination_size; }
    size_t get_combination_index(size_t index) { return m_indices[index]; }
private:
    size_t              m_set_size;
    size_t              m_combination_size;
    std::vector<size_t> m_indices;

    void check_arguments(size_t set_size, size_t combination_size);
};

lexicographical_combination_generator::
lexicographical_combination_generator(size_t set_size, size_t combination_size)
{
    check_arguments(set_size, combination_size);
    m_set_size = set_size;
    m_combination_size = combination_size;

    for (size_t index = 0; index < m_combination_size; ++index)
    {
        m_indices.push_back(index);
    }
}

void lexicographical_combination_generator::
check_arguments(size_t set_size, size_t combination_size)
{
    if (combination_size > set_size)
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "combination_size("
           << combination_size
           << ") > set_size("
           << set_size
           << ")";
        throw std::runtime_error{ss.str()};
    }

    if (set_size == 0)
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "set_size is zero";
        throw std::runtime_error{ss.str()};
    }
}

bool lexicographical_combination_generator::increment()
{
    if (m_indices[m_combination_size - 1] < m_set_size - 1)
    {
        m_indices[m_combination_size - 1]++;
        return true;
    }

    for (int i = (int)(m_combination_size - 2); i >= 0; --i)
    {
        if (m_indices[i] < m_indices[i + 1] - 1)
        {
            m_indices[i]++;

            for (int j = i + 1; j < m_combination_size; ++j)
            {
                m_indices[j] = m_indices[j - 1] + 1;
            }

            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

template<typename Iter>
void print(lexicographical_combination_generator& gen, Iter begin)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < gen.get_combination_size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << gen.get_combination_index(i);
    }

    std::cout << ": ";

    for (size_t i = 0; i < gen.get_combination_size(); ++i)
    {
        auto iter = begin;
        std::advance(iter, gen.get_combination_index(i));
        std::cout << *iter;
    }

    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::vector<char> alphabet = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' };
    lexicographical_combination_generator gen(5, 3);
    do {
        print(gen, alphabet.begin());
    } while (gen.increment());
}
```

Comment: My output is correct. You forgot to count the initial combination I didn't display in my example. // I'm still reading your post

Comment: @papagaga Ok got it. My bad.

Comment: @papagaga Ah, of course. You first increment `12345` and only after that you print it.

Comment: A stateful algorithm wasn't my purpose. I believe stateless is an interesting goal because you can parallelize efficiently. Given a sorted range as input, two rotations are enough to create another starting point. For example: thread 1: "12345", thread2: "23415" (of course it would be useful only for longer sequences)

Comment: @papagaga Fair enough.

Comment: @papagaga However, I believe you can parallelize my solution too.