# All combinations of two pairs of elements of an array

Tags: c++, combinatorics

Suppose I have an array of objects. Without loss of generality, it could be an array of indices:
$$a = (0, 1, 2, ..., n)$$
Now suppose I want to choose two pairs of elements of this array. The order is *not* of the matter inside pairs so for pairs itself.

For example if
$$a = (1,2,3,4)$$
then all those combinations would be 
$$(1,2), (3,4)\\(2,3), (1,4)\\...$$
But combinations like
$$(1,2), (3,4)\quad \text{and}\quad (4,3), (1,2)$$
should be considered as equivalent.

I am a little bit confused how to write compact and effective algorithm for my purpose. I feel that there is a way to do it for general case (not just for pairs) but I cannot find it. If you know, please share.

So far, here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>                                                                                             
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector< int > targetVector = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    std::vector< int > index_pair = { 2, 2, 1, 1, 0 };

    int pair1, pair2;
    do
    {
        //reset pairs to 00000
        pair1 = pair2 = 0;

        for ( int i = 0; i < (int)index_pair.size(); i++ )
        {
            if( index_pair[i] == 1 ) { pair1 += ( 1 << (i+1) ); }
            if( index_pair[i] == 2 ) { pair2 += ( 1 << (i+1) ); }
        }

        if ( pair1 > pair2 )
        {
            for ( auto index : index_pair )
            {
                std::cout << index;
            }
            std::cout << "\n";
        }
    }while( prev_permutation( index_pair.begin(), index_pair.end() ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output that seems to be right.

```
22110
22101
22011
21210
21201
21021
20211
20121
12210
12201
12021
10221
02211
02121
01221
```

Comment: There's no substantial difference I can see between what you're asking and the more classical combinatoric problem of enumerating distinct subsets in a set: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination. Just cut your 4-element subset in two and you'll have your pairs. So you would find a general answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430568/generating-combinations-in-c. Or, if you want to generate them one at a time, and if you don't mind the self-promotion: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/184586/generate-next-combination-in-lexicographic-order

Comment: I think it only works if an array consists of exactly 4 elements. Then yes, it is sufficient to choose only one pair. This does not work if there are more than 4 elements because one pair can belong to different combinations.

Comment: How do you get the pair `(4,5)` from the array `(1,2,3,4)`?  Am I missing something, or is there a typo?

Comment: Good catch! Thank you for noticing. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

## Unused variables

We never use `targetVector`, so we can omit its definition.

## Reduce scope

We can move `pair1` and `pair2` inside of the `do` loop.

## Don't cast to signed

This looks like a misguided attempt to appease a compiler warning:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)index_pair.size(); i++) {
```

Whilst it's good that you have enabled a good set of warnings, the better response would be to change the type of `i` to match (especially as we intend to use it as an indexer):

```
    for (std::size_t i = 0u;  i < index_pair.size();  ++i) {
```

We can also simplify the `if` chain if we use a small array for `pair`:

```
    std::size_t pair[3] = {};

    for (std::size_t i = 0u;  i < index_pair.size();  ++i)
        pair[index_pair[i]] += 1u << (i+1);

    if (pair[1] > pair[2]) {
```

We could use range-based `for` instead:

```
    std::size_t n = 0;
    for (auto i: index_pair)
        pair[i] += 1u << ++n;
```

It's not obvious whether this is better than the index loop, but you might prefer it.

## A typo

You appear to have misspelt `std::prev_permutation` in the `while` condition.

---

## Modified code

Without changing the algorithm, I have simplified to just

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> index_pair = { 2, 2, 1, 1, 0 };

    do {
        std::size_t pair[3] = {};

        for (std::size_t i = 0u;  i < index_pair.size();  ++i)
            pair[index_pair[i]] += 1u << (i+1);

        if (pair[1] > pair[2]) {
            for (auto index: index_pair) {
                std::cout << index;
            }
            std::cout << "\n";
        }
    } while (std::prev_permutation(index_pair.begin(), index_pair.end()));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a lot of useful remarks and corrections. P.S. it was really a typo with 'prev_permutation' but it compiles without warnings or errors. I use '-std=c++1y'.

Comment: It compiled cleanly for me, with GCC 7.2 and `-std=c++17`.  I'm not sure whether argument-dependent lookup finds the function, or whether it somehow makes its way into the global namespace (and I would appreciate clarification here!).  I'm constantly writing `size_t` without its `std::` (and did so several times writing my version), possibly because I also write some C from time to time.